# Django cannot login with email

Tags: python, django, backend

I'm trying to login with the email instead of the username. I don't know what I did wrong here. I filtered the DB from the Player instance in models.py which uses AbstractUser.

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .forms import PlayerCreationForm
from .models import Player

# REGISTER VIEW
def register_view(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = PlayerCreationForm()
        
    else:
        form = PlayerCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/credentials', json={'email': form.cleaned_data['email'], 'username': form.cleaned_data['username'], 
            'password': form.cleaned_data['password2']})
            return redirect('/login')

    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, "register.html", context)

# LOGIN VIEW
def login_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = Player.objects.filter(email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Incorrect email or password')

    return render(request, 'login.html')

# LOGOUT VIEW
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
    
# HOMEVIEW
def home_view(request):
    return render(request, "base.html")
```

I was given the error of

```
Internal Server Error: /login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stevek/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/stevek/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/stevek/Projects/Python/CRAFTMINE/web/accounts/views.py", line 39, in login_view
    login(request, user)
  File "/home/stevek/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 129, in login
    request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I can not use authenticate function because it only supports username and password by default.

Comment: Where you have `user = Player.objects.filter(email=email, password=password)`... try printing the `user` and tell me if you got a value from it. I know it going to throw the same error but I just want to know if the `user `is `None` or not. Because I think that `user` object is causing the problem.

Comment: Show your `models.py` for your `Player` model as well... That will be helpful also.

Comment: I got <QuerySet []> when I printed User

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Bpjt51Uy here is my models.py pastebin

Comment: So according the result printed from the `user` object... you have no database or stored objects for your `Player` model. But help me understand some more... You want `Player` to be a `user` right?

Comment: yes, right. i want player to be a user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234428/discussion-between-moi-myazz-and-steve).